# Oracle Find time from Seconds past midnight

Tags: oracle, time, seconds

In my Oracle table, I have a column with Number of Seconds since midnight (like 75135) and I want to identify its human readable time format. Do we have any command in Oracle ? please help me on this

Regards,
Manohar

Answer (score 1):

That is an interval:

```
select interval '1' second * 75135 from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 71370 * INTERVAL '1' SECOND,
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
       ) AS seconds_past_midnight
FROM   DUAL;
```

or

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 71370 / 86400,
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
       ) AS seconds_past_midnight
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which, outputs:

> | SECONDS_PAST_MIDNIGHT |
> | --- |
> | 2022-06-07 19:49:30 |

If you just want the time component then:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 71370 * INTERVAL '1' SECOND,
         'HH24:MI:SS'
       ) AS seconds_past_midnight
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which, outputs:

> | SECONDS_PAST_MIDNIGHT |
> | --- |
> | 19:49:30 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=248f3aabe65f40f02682d5351781f278)*

Answer (score 1):

Oracle provides the SSSSS format element that enables you to get the number of seconds past midnight from a given datetime value.

Example:

```
SELECT   TO_CHAR(TIMESTAMP '2022-06-07 00:01:05', 'SSSSS') as seconds_past_midnight
FROM DUAL;

SECONDS_PAST_MIDNIGHT
00065
```

Comment: This is going the wrong way - the OP already has the seconds value, e.g 75135?